# twitter bootstrap and cotainer not centering content of table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following dhtml skeleton

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Press me</a>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want table to be centered on the page. I am using latest version of bootstrap. My table is a very large width table. Sizes of the divs as this is shown on my chrome dev console are.

```
.content: 1583x3803
.container: 1170x3803 (with 206.5 margin left and right)
.table: 1334x3753
```

So I see that my table needs more space than the container has. I thought that container centers the divs according to their size. Is there a way to make my table no matter it's width to always center inside a div?

Comment: You probably want to be using `<div class="container-fluid">` rather than the standard `container` which hardcodes its sizes depending on the browser size.

Comment: @Varedis is right, also you can center a div or something like that with `center-block`